# Dynamic View that adjust to how long the Label text Swift

Tags: swift, dynamic, swift3, label

What I want to happen is that the rectangle view will adjust to how long the label is. Here are my codes

```
   @IBOutlet weak var rectangleView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

  let stringNumber = "123ewrqrqwerw4"
        let numberFromString = Int(stringNumber)

  rectangleView.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 100, width: self.view.frame.width * numberFromString, height: 50)
   self.label.text =  stringNumber
}
```

but my code is wrong.

Comment: are you using auto layout?

Comment: no sir @NazmulHasan

Comment: tried it, but its nil. I tried the CGFloat(numberFromString ?? 0) but the rectangle got lost

Comment: did you run at least one time `print(Int(stringNumber))`

Comment: yeah but still no :(

Comment: it shows but the rectangle doesn't get longer or shorter but good answer though

Comment: cool .. you used `self.view.frame.width` for full screen width  but `x: 15` from left , `top:100` and `height:50` . for example `numberFromString` (10 ) * `self.view.frame.width` (414.0) = what you expect ? that's why it width out of screen

Comment: Could you explain what you want to achieve ?